# Does a heavy document take much time in load from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using both `Firebase Database` and `Firestore` in my app. I store users data like name, email, uid etc small details in documents of a collection as *Users* in firestore. It works perfectly. I made a node as *Friends* in firebase database to store friends list of a user. So whenever user open the app, it calls his information from Users from firestore and also his friends list from Friends from firebase database.

Now the thing is by this way it calls data from the `Firestore` and  the `Firebase database`. So it means they are **2** requests/reads, one to *Friends* node and other to a document from *Users* collection. I think it would be better if i store friends list in Users document as an `Array`. So i will get only **1** read in Firestore. But i think that when the arrays of his friends list increases by 100+ elements. And also there are one or two more array lists like that. So will it take much time in retrieving a document from Users collection? or not? And which will be a better approach?

Here are the images of my current database structure as [Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0hlm.jpg) and [Friends](https://imgur.com/undefined).

Comment: Please don't include Realtime Database as a link or image. If the link breaks it would invalidate the question. Include those in the question as a short section of text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: It seems you're asking for our opinion about what's best for YOUR app. Without understanding the entire use case, it would be impossible to answer. If you are having difficulty with a section of code, thats *is* something we can help with. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's also not clear why you are using two different databases; using one would make the app easier to maintain and control. All Firebase products are very fast and getting information from Firebase depends on your internet and the amount of data. However, and this is important, generally speaking, whether your database has 10 or 10,000 documents/nodes if you retrieve 10, it will be about the same speed regardless of the overall amount of data. e.g. the speed at which you get data is not dependent on the total amount of stored data - it's more dependent on how much data you're getting from it.

Comment: Yes @Jay you are right, speed depends on how much data are we calling from the server not how much data is stored But here when i call a document then it will retrieve the whole data/fields and That's the question. Will document size reduce the speed of downloading data from firestore or not.  And i am using both database since there is a chatting feature which is less costly and faster if i use realtime db. And i stored friends list in firebase db because it's so fast for sending friend request, otherwise with Firestore it takes a second. But now i want to turn back to firestore for that.

Comment: It is not about 10 or 10000 documents. It is about 1 document having multiple large size arrays as fields of 100+ elements.

Comment: It's not clear what's being asked - let me explain why. As mentioned in the answer, Firestore documents have a maximum size of 1 MiB. That's the amount of data, regardless of configuration, that can be in a document. A document of that size, for example, loads in .083 seconds with a fast internet connection. So if there's less data it could shave off .002 seconds. As you can see, it's not really a number that has any kind of impact. Additionally a document having 100 fields is nothing; keeping in mind the 1MiB limit. So what's the actual issue? Can you clarify and provide a specific example?

Comment: Oh oh - and if you have not read it, please check out this brilliant Firestore Overview from @dougstevenson [top 10 things to know about Firestore](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-top-10-things-to-know-about-firestore-when-choosing-a-database-for-your-app-a3b71b80d979). It's kinda unrelated to the question but you mentioned large size arrays and there's has some fantastic pointers on organizing your data within Firestore.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much Jay  now i have understood the concept of speed. Now the question is should i use document's array or a subcollection for storing array lists as the doc's max size limit is 1MiB.

Comment: I generally recommend avoiding arrays in NoSQL databases. There are some heavy limits as to what you can/can not do with them and they (IMO) are inherently more challenging to work with. I suggest using a collection of documents, with auto-generated document id's to store your data. That totally get's around having to deal with arrays and eliminates your storage concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Firestore usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), the maximum size of a document is 1 MiB.

It means that as long as your `user` documents don't exceed the size limit, you can store `friends` data in arrays without a problem.

If you are planning to exceed the threshold, you may want to look for other options like creating **subcollections** to scale better as size of the subcollection doesn't affect the parent document's size in any way.

Comment: Hey @Farid,  I don't afraid of the size of a doc. I am talking about the speed. What if my doc get higher size then will it retrieve with the same speed or not! Do smaller documents retrieve faster ? Or if i make a subcollection of a document, will not it be 2 reads one for parent doc and other for child doc ? And if not then will it not be heavy to retrieve the parent doc ?

Answer (score 0):

I built a chat app in flutter with firebase using mapping for each chat Text(only one doc was used in chat between 2 users). I observed that after I filled 1MB of data in doc, my mobile downloaded the chat history at 10-12 kbps from firebase.
Maybe the speed was a coincidence but I am sure that as your data grows in a single firestore doc, the mobile app does not bursty download the whole document simultaneously, instead it downloads at a much slower speed.
Please correct me If I am wrong.